# vector size changes after push_back()

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am not sure why the `.size()` of a `vector<string> (10)` below is changing from 10 to 20 after `.push_back(string)` on it. I would assume it should remain the same.

```
int main() {

   vector<string> StrVec(10);
   vector<int>     intVec(10);
   iota(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), 1);

   cout << "StrVec.length = " << StrVec.size() << endl;

   for (int i : intVec)
   {
       StrVec.push_back(to_string(i));
   }

   cout << "StrVec.length = " << StrVec.size() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
StrVec.length = 10
StrVec.length = 20
```

Comment: It is exactly `push_back`'s job to add an element to the end of the vector, thereby increasing its size by one. What do you expect it to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `vector<string> StrVec(10);`, it initializes `StrVec` with 10 default-initialized `string` elements. Then, each `push_back()` pushes a new element to `StrVec` while iterating over `intVec`, thus arriving at 20 elements.

If you only wanted to pre-allocate memory (but not have any elements), you might consider using this instead:

```
vector<string> StrVec;
StrVec.reserve(10);
```

If you'd like to access elements of an already allocated vector, you might use `StrVec[i]`, where `i` is the index. Note that you might not index past the end of the vector.

Comment: Thank you - I was conceptually wrong about push_back(). StrVec[i] does the job.

Comment: @kaytu You were thinking that initializing the vector with `(10)` would pre-allocate the vector's `capacity()` and not its `size()`, and then `push_back()` would just fill in the existing memory. But that is not the case. If you want that, you need to use `reserve(10)` instead, like lorro showed above. `capacity()` and `size()` are two separate concepts.